# Maximum connected devices - Squid Proxy Server

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm using Squid like this:

```
acl whiteList src 111.111.111.111
http_access allow whiteList
http_access deny all
```

And I want to limit the number of maximum connected devices. Not maximum number of simultaneous connections.

Is there any configuration directive like: `maximum_connected_device 3`?
Or any other solutions/hacks?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help:

```
acl devicelimit maxconn 5
```

where `devicelimit` is an arbitrary name for the ACL rule. This will limit the connection from a single IP to 5.

http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/

Note: In the age of NAT, this isn't necessarily reliable as many clients might connect from the same IP address.